# Objective-C and regex

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have the following Objective-C code:

```
if(accountNumber!=nil)
    if(accountNumber!=nil){
```

a few lines down:

```
if(orderDate!=nil)
    if(orderDate!=nil){
```

so my question is this: is there a regex that will replace the 2nd line of text with just the curly brace? the "{"...

this is a piece of generated code and I don't have the generator so I have to massage the output and this is one of the pain points I get to look for...

Comment: Are you talking about a search and replace you want to do in Xcode or some other text editor to change your source code?

Comment: `(if\(\w+!=nil\))\s*\1\s*{` to replace with `$1{`.

Comment: maddy - yes.  basically i have to massage a generated file.

Comment: stribizhev i am confused by the \1\ and the $1...

Answer (score 0):

stribizhev's solution worked

```
Private Function RunOtherChanges(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim pattern As String = "(if\(\w+!=nil\))\s*\1\s*{"

    Dim replacement As String = "$1 {"
    Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
    Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(str, replacement)


    Return result
End Function
```